# Get the most recent observation using date variable in r

Tags: r, dplyr, partition

im using R to create a table with data from another table and i'm working with the next variables:

```
-PRODUCT ID 
-CLASIFICATION
-DATE
```

For example my origin table:

```
product id   Clasification   Date
10000567        B+         12-12-2020
10000123        C+         26-11-2020
10000567        A+         02-11-2020
10000222        A+         09-10-2020
10000123        B++        21-09-2020
10000222        A++        10-09-2020
```

The thing is that i need to get the most recently clasification for my products id's cause is a dynamic field and it can change always. One row for product id.

Any help will be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `slice_max()` in `dplyr`, which supersedes `top_n()` after version `1.0.0`, to select the most recent date.

```
df %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, "%d-%m-%Y")) %>%
  group_by(product_id) %>%
  slice_max(Date, n = 1) %>% 
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   product_id Clasification Date      
#        <int> <chr>         <date>    
# 1   10000123 C+            2020-11-26
# 2   10000222 A+            2020-10-09
# 3   10000567 B+            2020-12-12
```

---

***Data***

```
df <- structure(list(product_id = c(10000567L, 10000123L, 10000567L, 
10000222L, 10000123L, 10000222L), Clasification = c("B+", "C+", 
"A+", "A+", "B++", "A++"), Date = c("12-12-2020", "26-11-2020", 
"02-11-2020", "09-10-2020", "21-09-2020", "10-09-2020")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: What if i have more variables than those 3 that i mention? (i need include "Clasification" into the code)

Comment: @DiegoGonzalezAvalos `Clasification` is dependent on `product_id` and `Date` so that it doesn't need to be included in the code. It doesn't matter if you add more variables because other variables don't influence `Clasification`.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your dates are not sorted, something like the following should work:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
 arrange(desc(Date)) %>%
 group_by(id) %>%
 slice(1) %>%
 ungroup()
```

Comment: `Date` is not a standard `Date` object format, so `arrange()` takes it as character and sorts it alphabetically. E.g. `26-11-2020` is greater than `2-12-2020`, which is not reasonable.