# How to identify and remove duplicates with multiple condition in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, duplicates, data.table

I would like to identify and remove duplicates from my dataset. The issue is that I have two different criteria. First, the main criteria that I am using is the most recent time. However, not all duplicates have dates. On the cases dates are missing, I will have to check one by one to see which row I am going to keep. So, this is what I need:

Suppose I have the following data:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c("a", "a", "b","b", "c","c"),
                 date = c("2023-05-16", "2023-08-21", "2023-06-05", NA, "2023-05-07", "2023-05-20"))

library(lubridate)

df$date <- ymd(df$date)
class(df$date)

[1] "Date"

df

  id       date
1  a 2023-05-16
2  a 2023-08-21
3  b 2023-06-05
4  b       <NA>
5  c 2023-05-07
6  c 2023-05-20
```

First, I need to identify all duplicates that contain NA to compare the rows and see which row I will keep. I need a resulting dataframe similar to this, it contains the duplicate and the unique value:

```
  id       date
1  b 2023-06-05
2  b       <NA>
```

Notice that I have both rows so I can compare them. I am keeping the examples simple, but I am not sure on my actual data frame how many duplicates per id I have. Next, I will be left with the remaining dataframe:

```
  id       date
1  a 2023-05-16
2  a 2023-08-21
3  c 2023-05-07
4  c 2023-05-20
```

I need to keep only the most recent of the values, and I will end with something like this:

```
  id       date
1  a 2023-08-21
2  c 2023-05-20
```

Let me know if something isn't clear and you need more clarification.

Comment: Why b is no longer included? Did you show the expected result?

Comment: Notice that b's have two rows, and one of them have NA instead of date. I need to identify all cases similar to b and put them into a different data frame. This is because cases with no dates, I will have to check individually which is the correct row.

Comment: something like `subset(df, as.logical(ave(date, id, FUN = \(x)all(length(x)>1 & !is.na(x)) & min(na.omit(x))==x)))`???

Comment: Check out this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63020956/get-the-most-recent-observation-using-date-variable-in-r e.g. `df %>% slice_max(order_by = date, by = id, n = 1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part 1: Identify all duplicates that contain NA and keep them in a separate df for review:

```
#Ids of NA dates:
ids_na <- df |> filter(is.na(date)) |> pull(id)

#Dfs of duplicates with NA:
is_na <- df |> filter(id %in% ids_na)

is_na

# id       date
# b 2023-06-05
# b       <NA>
```

Part 2: keep most recent entry of duplicated values

```
# Remove dupes with NAs from df
clean_df <- df |> filter(!(id %in% ids_na))
# Get the most recent by grouping 
unique_entries <- clean_df |> group_by(id) |>  summarise(date = max(date))
unique_entries

# A tibble: 2 × 2
# id    date      
# <chr> <date>    
#   a     2023-08-21
#   c     2023-05-20
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a flag rather than split. Using `ave` you can flag which id has `anyNA` in the date, create a `keep` vector to subset either the valid or the invalid ones. Get the latest date using `which.max`.

```
> df <- transform(df, flag=ave(as.integer(date), id, FUN=anyNA))
> keep <- !df$flag == 1
> by(df[keep, ], df[keep, ]$id, \(x) x[which.max(x$date), ]) |> do.call(what='rbind')
  id       date flag
a  a 2023-08-21    0
c  c 2023-05-20    0
> df[!keep, ]
  id       date flag
3  b 2023-06-05    1
4  b       <NA>    1
```

#### Update

Just noticed, since R4.3.0 we can use a formula in `by`.

```
> by(df[keep, ], ~id, \(x) x[which.max(x$date), ]) |> do.call(what='rbind')
  id       date flag
a  a 2023-08-21    0
c  c 2023-05-20    0
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(id = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c"), date = structure(c(19493, 
19590, 19513, NA, 19484, 19497), class = "Date"), flag = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: I am having a problem when generating the flag column. I think it's because of anyNA function is searching for any NA across all columns, which makes flag column report 1 to all rows in my dataset. Any idea how I can fix it? I guess I would need flag to report 1 only for date column instead of all columns.

Comment: @VictorShin Look up documentation `?ave` what this function does, the code only should scan date column _by_ id for NA's. Perhaps you have different column names in your real data.